# Regex expression matches a string

Tags: java, regex

Can anybody explain me why the following expression:

```
"(\\(.+\\)\\:[' ']?[-+]?[0-9]+\\.?[\\d]*[;]?)+"
```

is matching

```
(ABAS) ;(ABDS): 4.0;
```

but is not matching

```
(ABDS): 4.0;(ABAS) ;
```

Comment: The first string matches `.+` to `ABAS) ;(ABDS`. It might help if you change `.+` to `[^)]+`.

Comment: In the first case, are you aware that `\(.+\)` will match `(ABAS) ; (ABDS)`?

Answer (score 0):

Because you explicitly match the `:` symbol after anything, but not `;` symbol